# Homology groups of $S^1 \times (S^1 \vee S^1)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

How to compute all homology groups of

$S^1 \times (S^1 \vee S^1)$?

Thank you. I don't see how to define a simplicial structure.

Comment: For some intuition, think of this space as a torus with another torus glued on an 'outer circle' to and 'inner circle' of the first torus.

Comment: I am aware of this. And I know the $\Delta$-structure for torus. But how to combine this to get a $\Delta$-structure for my space?

Comment: Have you drawn a picture? If it helps, draw it as $[0,1]\times (S^1\vee S^1)$ with the ends identified. A simplicial (or cellular) decomposition should be fairly obvious.

Comment: just use cellular decomposition instead simplicial one